# mixing jquery with angularjs a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

let say I want to hover on a link to fadeOut a button, and apply event to when it's click. I can use ng-click but how to do the hover thing with angular? I'm not familiar with pure js. It's a good practice I mix up with jquery.

Comment: We are using angular with jquery without any issue. The basic rule is we try to do everything with angular and the rest with jquery. [Read here](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) on *Does Angular use the jQuery library?* and read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: I use ng-class for tabs, hover.

Comment: would the angular's mouse enter serve as your 'hover'? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery** is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML , Its basically javascript made simple and light weight its used for perfect client side processes, And for creating an abstraction to the lower levels so as to increase the efficency of javascript, And jquery is a **scripting language** but

**AngularJS** is an open-source JavaScript framework, whose aim is to build single page applications with **MVC** capability and i think AngularJS is something that we cant consider simply as a scripting language , Mixing them both is like mixing html with javascript, they are functionally so different and its really harmless in my view

Answer (score 0):

I can't be labeled as a good practice to add jquery to angular because Angular provides a lite version of jquery (jqlite).

Good practice is to code in angular without jquery at first to fully understand the underlying concepts and no to code the jquery way

However there is no problem (common practice vs good practice) to include jquery if you need it (use of plugin for example)